# from where & from which, during which & during which time

Tags: meaning, phrases

Could you explain the differences between:
1. from where & from which;
2. during which & during which time.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that during which & during which or _during where & during which _ ?

Comment: did you check dictionaries and the words' usage?

Comment: @MaulikV Can you please assist me with this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/ideal-term-for-the-payment-scenario)

Comment: General questions are off topic. Though - *From where did you get this shirt.* *From which* is not a good phrase to start a question with. Also, prefer *what time* instead of *which time.*

Comment: @MaulikV: From which source did you get the idea that you shouldn't start a question with that? ;)

Comment: @oerkelens lol. nice! In fact, beginning the question with preposition sounds redundant unless you mention the specific sources in the question. *Which dictionary did you search* = *From which dictionary did you search.* BUT *From which dictionary did you search, Oxford or Collins?*

Answer (score 3):

If I want to know where something or someone came from, then the *general* question I can ask is

> From where did you get that?

This question could get different answers, like *from Thailand*, or *from a little store on Main Street*. The answers are answers to different interpretations of the general question. *Where* is basically a short form of *which place*!

However, if I know that it is an object bought in a store, and I want to know the store where it was bought, I can ask a more *specific* question:

> From which store did you get that?

Now, obviously, *from Thailand* is no longer a valid answer!

So, in short, if you do not specify what kind of place you are asking about, you can ask *from which place*, or in short ***from where***.

---

The difference between *during which* and *during which time* is a different issue.

You use *during which* when you refer to something, an event, that was happening, while at the same time something else happened:

> We had a great lunch, during which my father gave a speech.

You use *during which time* to indicate that something happened in the time-span that is taken by something else.

> She spend hours doing her make-up, during which time I managed to finish reading "War and Peace".

The main difference between the two phrases is the implication that my father gave a speech *at* the mentioned dinner - he was present there, and the speech was given in the presence of the diners. If I would have said *during which time my father gave a speech*, he could have been anywhere else, giving a speech, but not to the people at the dinner!

In the second sentence, I have been reading my book, but that was not something that was part of her doing her make-up, I probably wasn't even present.

To show this contrast with two similar phrases:

> The class lasted two hours, during which we read *Hamlet*.
>   The class lasted two hours, during which time we read *Hamlet*.

The fist sentence means that this was probably a literature class, and reading the play was part of that class - everyone read the play together. *During which* refers to *the class*.

The second sentence gives the impression that the class was possibly boring, or "we" were not even present, but instead of paying attention to the class, we read the play. *During which time* refers to the two hours, the *time* that the class lasted.

Comment: Hi. I fully understood the answer to the second question. Thanks! Actually I meant to ask how to use them in Attributive Clause. Could you answer again the first question?